# Error when using "ubuntu-vm-builder" command to create Ubuntu11.10 guest on Ubuntu11.10 host

Tags: installation, virtualization

I want to create guest os(Ubuntu11.10) on host(Ubuntu11.10)
with "ubuntu-vm-builder" command.
some error is occured

do you know how to diagnose to this case ?
please Give me a piece of advice.
My log is following
https://gist.github.com/1670826

I worked with following article: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests

Answer (score 2):

I was building a 10.04 image on a 11.04 server and had to do the following to get it to work:

1. Edit VMBuilder's dapper.py (even if you're not building dapper).  Mine was located at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/plugins/ubuntu/dapper.py
2. Search for "def unmount_dev(self):" and add the two 'sleep' and 'chroot' commands to match the following:

   ```
   def unmount_dev(self):
       self.context.cancel_cleanup(self.unmount_dev)
       run_cmd('sleep', '10')
       run_cmd('chroot', '%s' % self.context.chroot_dir, '/etc/init.d/cron','stop')
       run_cmd('umount', '%s/dev' % self.context.chroot_dir)
   ```

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vm-builder/+bug/879710 for more info.